# adding contents of a file to a webform using applescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, webforms, web-scraping, applescript

I'm trying to add the contents of a text file (in this case json) to a webform. 
the data is a json list/array like:
`[{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3}]`
Which is saved in 'myfile.json'.

I'm trying to open a webpage that requires auth, but doesn't have a friendly API for auth. For example, I'm just going to use stackoverflow.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
set fileContents to (read POSIX file "myfile.json" as «class utf8»)

tell application "Safari"
    if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    activate
    set URL of document 1 to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
    delay 2
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('wmd-input').value=" & fileContents in document 1
end tell
```

this seems to work pretty well, except at the end all that gets pasted into the textfield is

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object >Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object >Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

How can I get the actual contents of the file into the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do JavaScript "document.getElementById('wmd-input').value=" & fileContents in document 1` will be evaluated to `document.getElementById('wmd-input').value=[{...},{...}]` (a list of objects).

An options is to use JSON.stringify() to transform the `fileContents` into a real string, or, add `"` to the `fileContents`

`'document.getElementById("wmd-input").value=JSON.stringify(' & fileContents  & ')'`
`'document.getElementById("wmd-input").value=\"' & fileContents  & '\"'`

Comment: The json stringify function worked for me. Oddly though, Applescript doesn't seem to like how you have your quotes. It likes singles in place of your doubles and vice-versa. Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

If you do a lot of this, you might want to look at Fake, which is an AppleScript-able Web browser that is available in Mac App Store. It is really easy to automate the filling of forms and other user actions, for testing or whatever other purpose.